# Verify if linear combination of vectors is in lattice

Tags: linear-algebra, integer-lattices

Let $\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}$ and $\mathbf{c}$ be vectors in $\Bbb{R}^3$. How do I verify if there is a linear combination of them that belongs in the lattice $\mathcal{L}(B)$ where $B = \{(1,1,1)\}$?

Comment: I'm studying this on my own, so I hope the question makes sense. If not, I'd be happy to understand why and how to correct it.

Comment: Well if $a,b,c$ form a basis this is gonna be true trivially. But what do you mean by the lattice $\mathcal{L}(B)$? Is this $\{(n,n,n)|n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$?

Comment: But what about arbitrary vectors (that possibly don't form a basis)? Yes, that's what I meant. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1) Check if your vectors are linearly independent. If they are this becomes trivial and the answer is yes.

2) If the answer is no, reduce $\{a,b,c\}$ to a set of independent vectors $\Gamma$.

pos 1: $\Gamma = \{a\}$. Check if $a$ is of the form $(n,n,n)$.

pos 2: $\Gamma = \{a,b\}$. check if the system of equations $\lambda a + \mu b = (1,1,1)$ has a solution.

Comment: Out of interest: why do you need this. ie. what are you studying? :)